# How to add a leading zero Velocity Template for small integer numbers?

Tags: string, numbers, velocity

How to add a leading zero in .vm Velocity Template for one-digit numbers 0..9?

As example, `${val}` shows 9. How to display 09 instead?

For integer number more than 9 do nothing and display as it is with not additional zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using if-else:

```
#if(${val} < 10) 0${val} #else ${val} #end
```